# Creation of node package for icon font

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, webfonts

I am new to the node. I want to create package in node where other's can use this package by using simple steps like.

```
npm install <my-font-icon-package>
```

I have generated by font icons using iconmoon. I have all the files with me related to font.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a github repo.
2. Clone the repo to your machine.
3. Do an `npm init`(haver to be logged in. If not, do `npm login`)
4. Push your code to github.
5. Do an `npm publish`

This will publish it, and the name of the package will be the one provided in `package.json` at the time of `npm init`. Refer [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages) for more details.